# Software Packages for Simple 2D games using Python

Tags: python, gui

I would like to write some simple board games using Python and I want to display them using some simple GUI for Python. I am looking for recommendations on what to use for this?

Comment: Have you looked at pygame? https://www.pygame.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The** go to library for game writing in python is called [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org) it should have everything that you need for simple *or complex* board games including GUI with various backends.

Comment: it's based on SDL and very similar in interface.